# subclass tuple with typed arguments

Tags: python-3.x, mypy

Should the following work?  If not, why not, how to understand, and how to fix?  (This example just exposes the problem, so please answer in terms of subclassing `tuple`; I already know about `NamedTuple`.)

```
class Point(tuple):
    def __new__(cls, f1: float, f2: float):
        self = super().__new__(cls, (f1,f2))
        return self
```

mypy 0.761 considers this an error:

```
error: Argument 2 to "__new__" of "tuple" has incompatible type "Tuple[float, float]"; expected "Iterable[_T_co]"
```

Comment: A namedtuple is a subclass of `tuple`, so it's not clear why using namedtuple wouldn't solve your problem.

Comment: A tuple accepts `Any`, and not just `float`. Replace `float` with `Any` from `from typing import Any` and this should work.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to keep the types in `Point` as `float`, then cast f1 and f2 to Any when passing it to tuple, via `self = super().__new__(cls, (cast(Any, f1), cast(Any, f2)))`

Comment: @Melvin This is probably the nub of my confusion.  Why is a `float` not accepted where an `Any` is?  A `float` should be an `Any`.

Comment: @Alan yeah sorry it doesn't make sense to me either. For some reason mypy's fine with `tuple.__new__(cls, (f1,f2))`.

Comment: I have this exact same problem. One reason to want to subclass `tuple` instead of using `namedtuple` is if you want to assert input values, like `f1` and `f2` need to be positive.